# How to launch Microsoft Edge in IE mode using Selenium Java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-edgedriver, selenium-java

I'm launch Microsoft Edge in IE mode using Selenium Java.

Can someone help me with the required configuration settings?

Comment: Googling "selenium use edge in ie mode", this was literally the first hit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/ie-mode?tabs=java :(

Answer (score 0):

To launch Microsoft Edge browser in IE mode and navigate to a website e.g. `http://www.bing.com` you can use the following configuration and settings:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerOptions;

public class IEDriverSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        InternetExplorerOptions ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
        ieOptions.attachToEdgeChrome();
        ieOptions.withEdgeExecutablePath("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieOptions);
        driver.get("http://www.bing.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesnt work either. i also referred the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/ie-mode?tabs=java. But its throwing me the error

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. IELaunchURL() returned HRESULT 80070002 ('The system cannot find the file specified.') for URL 'http://localhost:52310/'
Build info: version: '4.1.1', revision: 'e8fcc2cecf'